# Multiple fields appearing under a parent in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```js
class CriteriaSetValue extends Component {
  state = {
  
    count: 0,

    tableName: "",
    fieldName:"",

    tables: [],
    fields: [],
    addLine: [],
    addField: []
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const addField = this.state.addField;
    const size = addField.length + 1;
    addField.push(size);
    this.setState({
      addField
    });

addNewLine = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const addLine = this.state.addLine;
    const size = addLine.length + 1;
    const nextLine = this.state.count + 1;
    addLine.push(size);
    this.setState({
      count: nextLine,
      addLine
    });
  };

 render() {
    const {showForm, tableName, fieldName } = this.state;

    const { props, state } = this;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      

        <div className="form-wrapper">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-10 container">
              <form onSubmit={this.submit} className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                  <h3 className="card-title">
                    Criteria Set
                    {/* <Locale value="std.formupload" /> */}
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                     
                      <div className="add-line">
                        <Button
                          icon
                          labelPosition="left"
                          onClick={this.addNewLine}
                        >
                          Add Line
                          <Icon name="plus" />
                        </Button>
                        {this.state.addLine.map(index => {
                          return (
                            <div
                              className="field-line"
                              style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}
                              key={index}
                              id={index}
                            >
                              <h4 className="field-button">Line {index}</h4>
                              <Button
                                className="field-button"
                                icon
                                onClick={this.toggleForm}
                              >
                                <Icon name="box" />
                              </Button>
                            </div>
                          );
                          
                        })
                        }

                        {
                          this.state.addField.map(index => {
                          return (
                            <React.Fragment>
                              <div
                                className="field-button"
                                style={{
                                  marginTop: "20px",
                                  paddingLeft: "20px"
                                }}
                                key={index}
                                id={index}
                              >
                        
                                <h4
                                  className="field-button"
                                  onclick={this.addCriteriaValue}
                                >
                                  <span>
                                    table.field
                                   
                                  </span>
                                </h4>

                                <Button
                                  className="field-button"
                                  icon
                                  onClick={this.toggleDelete}
                                >
                                  <Icon name="delete calendar" />
                                </Button>
                              </div>
                              <br></br>
                            </React.Fragment>
                          );
                        })
                        }
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
};
```

This is kind of related to what I am trying to achieve: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/3vqyo8xlx5

But I want the child to appear under the preference of where the "Add child" button is clicked, not on the last one.

I am working on making multiple fields to appear under each line when a button beside line1, line2 and so on is clicked, but currently, the field jump to last lines when a button is clicked, it is not appearing on the appropriate line.
[image]

I have been able to show lines when the "Add Line" button is clicked and I have also been able to show the field when the button beside "Line #1" is clicked.

[image]

I want the fields for "Line #1" to show under the line1 when the field button is clicked, the field for "Line #2" to show under the line2 when the field button beside it is clicked and so on

[image]

Comment: Could be an asynchronous problem. React sometimes collects setState functions and does them in bulk for performance reasons. To ensure that the updates happen directly, you can use the callback of setState:
addNewLine = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => {
       const { addLine, count } = prevState;
       const size = addLine.length + 1;
      addLine.push(size);
      count: count + 1;,
      addLine
    });
  };

Comment: This is kind of related to what  I am trying to achieve:   https://codesandbox.io/s/3vqyo8xlx5                                                                      But I want the child to appear under the field of where the button on add child is clicked, not on the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const AddButton = ({ label, onClick }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick}>
    {label} [+]
  </button>
)

const FieldData = ({ label, criterias, onAdd, onDelete }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div
      className='field-button'
      style={{
        marginTop: '20px',
        paddingLeft: '20px'
      }}
    >
      <h4 className='field-button'>
        <AddButton
          label='Add criteria'
          onClick={onAdd}
        />
        <span>
          {label}
        </span>
      </h4>
      {criterias.map((item, idx) => (
        <p key={idx}>{item.id}</p>
      ))}
      <button
        className='field-button'
        onClick={onDelete}
      >
        Del [-]
      </button>
    </div>
    <br />
  </React.Fragment>
)

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    lines: []
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('DATA TO SAVE ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.lines))
  }
  
  handleAddLine = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      lines: [
        ...prevState.lines,
        {
         id: (prevState.lines.length + 1),
         fields: []
        }
      ]
    }))
  }
  
  handleAddField = lineId => e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newLines = [ ...prevState.lines ]
      const curLine = newLines[newLines.findIndex(({ id }) => id === lineId)]

      curLine.fields.push({
        id: curLine.fields.length + 1,
        criterias: []
      })
      
       return {
        ...prevState,
        lines: newLines
      }
    })
  }

  handleAddCriteria = (lineId, fieldId) => event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newLines = [ ...prevState.lines ]
      const curLine = newLines[newLines.findIndex(({ id }) => id === lineId)]
      const curField =  curLine.fields[curLine.fields.findIndex(({ id }) => id === fieldId)]

      curField.criterias.push({
        id: curField.criterias.length + 1
      })
      
      return {
        ...prevState,
        lines: newLines
      }
    })
  }
  
  handleDeleteField = (lineId, fieldId) => event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newLines = [ ...prevState.lines ]
      const curLine = newLines[newLines.findIndex(({ id }) => id === lineId)]
      curLine.fields =  curLine.fields.filter(item => item.id !== fieldId)
      
      return {
        ...prevState,
        lines: newLines
      }
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { lines } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className='form-wrapper'>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-10 container'>
              <form
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                className='card' 
              >
                <div className='card-header'>
                  <h3 className='card-title'>
                    Criteria Set
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div className='card-body'>
                  <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-md-7 col-lg-8'>
                      <div className='add-line'>
                        <AddButton
                          label='Add Line'
                          onClick={this.handleAddLine}
                        />
                        {lines.map((line, idx) => {
                          return (
                            <React.Fragment key={idx}>
                              <div
                                className='field-line'
                                style={{ marginTop: '30px' }}
                              >
                                <h4 className='field-button'>
                                  Line {idx+1}
                                </h4>
                                <AddButton
                                  label='Add field'
                                  onClick={this.handleAddField(line.id)}
                                />
                              </div>
                              {line.fields.map((lField, idx) => (
                                <FieldData
                                  label={idx+1}
                                  criterias={lField.criterias}
                                  onAdd={this.handleAddCriteria(line.id, lField.id)}
                                  onDelete={this.handleDeleteField(line.id, lField.id)}
                                />
                              ))}                    
                            </React.Fragment>
                          )
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I defined a new data structure for the state, so It is better to think about nested data, and I refactored the code a little.

Comment: Thanks Mauro. I was able to refactor with the help of your code. It really helps a lot. Thank you so much